# Setting up biber as a default biblatex backend in the configuration file

Tags: biblatex, biber

The `biblatex` release notes recommend to setup `backend=biber` in `biblatex.cfg`, however LaTeX refuses to accept this text in `biblatex.cfg`:

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\endinput
```

LaTeX says, "The package biblatex has already been loaded with options..."

How to set up backend parameter in here properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Load `biblatex` in your main document using `\usepackage[<options>]{biblatex}`. Your configuration file `biblatex.cfg` should look as follows:

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{backend=biber}
\endinput
```

UPDATE: As Jonathan has hinted, with `biblatex` v2.0 (released July 2012) `backend` has become a loadtime option, so it is not possible anymore to select the backend engine (biber, BibTeX etc.) via `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. Also note that biber (not BibTeX) is now the default backend.

Comment: You beat me by two minutes. :)

Comment: @egreg: I know that feeling. ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work anymore! At least in v2.2 `backend` is a loadtime option, so this produces an error.