# Chicago-biblatex error

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am very new to LaTeX and the world of programming in general, and I am writing my M.A. thesis using LaTeX.  The Chicago style is required for my thesis, so I got the `biblatex-chicago` package.  this is an outline of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}

\bibliography{refs}

\begin{document}

--then the body of the paper with some citations and the \printbibliography command--

\end{document}
```

When I run it through BibTeX, I get the following errors:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)

The top-level auxiliary file: Bodhi Ch. 1.aux

I found no \citation commands---while reading file Bodhi Ch. 1.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Bodhi Ch. 1.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Bodhi Ch. 1.aux
```

(There were 3 error messages)

Also, the bibliography and the citations don't come out, presumably because BibTeX was not able to process the file.

The name of my project is "Bodhi Ch. 1"

Anyone know what this is about?

Comment: You Have to compile the bibliography with `biber` not `bibtex`. To use `bibtex` you have to specify `backend=bibtex` as one of the options of `biblatex`. Also remember to include the extension `bib` for the bibliography file.

Comment: @Guido The part with the `.bib` extension for the bibliography file depends on the way you include it. If you include it using the `\bibliography` command (as the questioner does) you must not use it. If you use the `\addbibresource` command, you need it.

Comment: @BenediktBauer The `.bib` is optional with `\bibliography`. According to the `biblatex` manual `\bibliography` is maintained for legacy document, but it is otherwise deprecated

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I got it up and running by putting [backend=bibtex] as an option for the \usepackage{biblatex-chicago} command.  By the way, what are the pros and cons of using biber vs. bibtex as a compiler?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things here:

1. You are using `bibtex` instead of what it seems you want to use, `biblatex`.  For this, you first need to change the path to the executable file.  I cannot tell you how to do this because I do not know what type of editor you are using, but for example, if using TeXnicCenter it's just a matter of changing this on the profile settings.
2. If you actually want to use `bibtex` (which I personally prefer... but many folks around here just love `biblatex`) you need to:

   2.1 Instead of `\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate]{biblatex}` change it for `\usepackage{natbib}`

   2.2 You need to create a `.bib` file which contains the bibliography entries.

   2.3 In order to not get the warnings, you actually need to `\cite` any of the authors of your `.bib` file (thus eliminating the problem of not finding `\citation` commands) , and of course this file should not be empty (thus eliminating the problem of not finding `\bibdata` and finally you have to set a `\bibliographystyle`, that since you are using the `natbib` package mentioned at the beginning, you'll get the options to choose the style you want.

   2.3.1 As it seems the style you need is Chicago, this could be implemented by `\bibliographystyle{chicagoa}`
3. Now, if you want to use `biblatex` it is usually recommended to go along with `biber`.  This could be a good starting point: [Setting up biber as a default biblatex backend in the configuration file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27160/setting-up-biber-as-a-default-biblatex-backend-in-the-configuration-file)

Comment: I am using TeXShop for Mac.  There is a pull-down menu for which program to run the .tex file through, and here there are options for LaTeX, XeLaTeX, and BibTeX, but no option for BibLaTeX.  This is why I used BibTeX to process it.  How would I run it through BibLaTeX instead?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I got it up and running.